DockPanelSuite float Document area
Sample setup, I have 5 tabs in the DockState.Document view, and 1 tab in DockState.DockRight

I have these 2 methods. The first floats the current active tab. It works fine. The 2nd is supposed to float the entire Document view. But it only picks up a few of the tabs and leaves some behind.
private void toolstripWindowFloat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dockMain.ActiveDocument.DockHandler.DockState = DockState.Float;
}

private void toolstripWindowFloatAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dockMain.ActivePane.DockState = DockState.Float;
}

You can see here, the float got 3 of the tabs and 2 were left behind.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix it?
